# Can zircons be analysed by the (U+Th)/He after being ablated for analysis of U-Pb?

Tags: geology, geochemistry, geochronology, isotopic

I have zircons that have been mounted in a resin block. They have been polished to approximately half way through the zircons (as is convention) and they have been ablated to attain the U-Pb or Pb-Pb ages. I am unfamiliar with the intricacies of the (U+Th)/He method. Can these zircons still be analysed for (U+Th)/He? Or would the ablation affect the results? Furthermore, would the zircons need to be extracted from the resin blocks? If so, what would be the best method of extraction?

Comment: (U+Th)/He is going to be by solution, no by LA, am I right?

Comment: That's right. So the problem would be getting the zircons out. I don't know if there are people out there that have done this kind of thing. And again, I don't know if the ablation process may affect the results for (U+Th)/He

Comment: I would suspect that the isotope ratios my be disrupted at the ablation wall holes. Maybe leaching that stuff somehow to leave only pristine zircon? No idea. I would do a literature search to see if someone has done it before. Look at their methods section, and possibly email the corresponding author.